# How to remove the Title Bar of Gnome applications

Tags: linux, gnome, titlebar, window-decoration, openbox

## Problem

##### I have one Ubuntu20 Desktop(`Gnome`) and I want it to be fully black and ideal. As reference, I have taken one Ubuntu20 Server and Installed `openbox` on it.

I hided the title bar of all the applications in `OpenBox` by editing the configurations in `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` and added

```
<application class="*">
      <decor>no</decor>
      <maximized>false</maximized>
    </application>

</applications>
```

So that it will hide the title-bar of all the applications. Also, I am able to achieve my demand. Image shown below as example.
[image: openbox]

I want to perform the same on Gnome Desktop as well, but I don't know which config file to be edited for the same.
Currently, my `Gnome` Looks like this
[image: gnome]

Any help for the following is appreciated
Thank you.

#### NOTE: I don't want to use only terminal, but will be using other applications like Firefox, chrome, VLC, etc. without title-bar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Well, after a few days of searching... I found the solution for my own question.

##### This  might be not the correct way to solve it, but can be used to make things work.

> 1. We need to make sure that Gnome works with Extention.
> 2. We need to Install Unite Extention for that.
> 3. Disable all the setting shown below in Unite Extention to get the desired output.

### How to enable extensions

Install `gnome-tweaks tool`

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then you can see your application on `Show Application > Tweaks`

## Method 1 Use gnome-shell-extensions package [easiest and safest way]

#### Step 1 Install Gnome Shell Extention

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

You’ll have to reboot your system (or maybe just restart GNOME Shell by pressing `<ALT>+F2` and type `r` and Press `Enter`,  I don’t remember it at this point). After that, start GNOME Tweaks, and you’ll find a few extensions installed. You can just toggle the button to start using an installed extension.

#### Step 2 Install Unite Extention

```
wget https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell/releases/download/v64/unite-shell-v64.zip
```

For the latest release go to `https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell/releases`

And then Extract to extension folder of your home directory

```
unzip unite-shell-v64.zip -d ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Then reboot or reload your Gnome shell by `<ALT>+F2` then `r` and `Enter`

## Method 2: Install GNOME Shell extensions from a web browser

GNOME project has an entire website dedicated to extensions. That’s not it. You can find, install, and manage your extensions on this website itself. No need even for GNOME Tweaks tool.

Website : https://extensions.gnome.org/

#### Step 1: Install browser add-on

You can simply click on the suggested add-on link by your web browser. You can install them from the link below as well:

For Google Chrome, Chromium, and Vivaldi: [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep).

For Firefox: [Mozilla Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/).

For Opera: [Opera Addons](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/gnome-shell-integration/)

#### Step 2: Install native connector

Just installing browser add-on won’t help you. You’ll still see an error like:

`“Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector”`

This is because you haven’t installed the host connector yet. To do that, use this command:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Don’t worry about the ‘chrome’ prefix in the package name. It has nothing to do with Chrome. You don’t have to install a separate package for Firefox or Opera here.

Now head over to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/ and Turn On the Extention.

## Done It's Installed

## Now go to extensions and open settings for Unite

[image]

and disable all settings like this
[image]

&
[image]

##### Now Close the settings and you are done!

#### Now Your decorators are hidden.

[image]

Comment: Totally works! Do not forget to install Xorg utilities as mentionned in the [docs](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) and to reboot...

Answer (score 1):

The decorator is not hidden but black in your case because you changed something else to make them black, this only gets rid of the controls:  You should have noticed that, and it's not the same as your first screenshot.

Comment: You are right. Screenshots are not accurate but the process works